# Using dispatch group in tableView(_ tableView:, cellForRowAt indexPath:) delegate method; "Expression of type UITableViewCell is unused"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am trying to call an asynchronous function (observing a Firebase database value) and use a dispatch group to notify when the data has been pulled from said asynchronous function.

This is happening within my tableView(_ tableView:, cellForRowAt indexPath:) UITableViewDelegate method. I first declare "cell" as a a custom subclass of UITableViewCell (in this case, "CommentCell"). I then create the dispatch group, enter the group, pull the data from firebase, use said data to populate my cell, and then leave/notify the dispatch group. When the group is notified, I simply want to return my cell.

For whatever reason, the function is saying I'm not returning a UITableViewCell, even though there is only one path that my function could go down, and that ends with a return of the CommentCell. The issue is likely caused by the fact that I am getting this error when trying to return the cell:

> Expression of type 'CommentCell?' is unused

Here is my tableView(_ tableView:, cellForRowAt indexPath:) delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: CommentCell!

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    group.enter()
    Database.database().reference().child("Users/\(comments[indexPath.row].uid)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let data = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CommentCell
        cell.parentVC = self
        cell.uid = self.comments[indexPath.row].uid
        cell.photoUrl = data["photoUrl"] as? String
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "profile")?.resize(targetSize: CGSize(width: 35, height: 35))
        cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 17.5
        self.loadImage(string: cell.photoUrl, cell: cell)
        cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.textLabel?.text = data["name"] as? String
        cell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = .darkGray
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.comments[indexPath.row].text
        cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        return cell
    }
}
```

Attached is an image of the code and errors.

[image]

Comment: You can't try to return a cell asynchronously. That won't work.

Comment: Please search before asking. The question of how to populate a table with downloaded data has been discussed here many, many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in `tableView(_:,cellForRowAt:)` you *must* return the cell synchronously / immediately. This is not the place where you can wait for content to load from the network or file system since this would block the UI. In order to load data asynchronously, do something similar to the following:

- set up a custom cell that displays a placeholder or a loading indicator. Return this cell synchronously. At the same time, start loading the content.
- once the content is available, update the cell

Back to your code, there's no `wait()` call in your function, hence the control flow will just run to the end of the function and never come past a return (the `notify` function won't block!). That's why you get the error message.